# How can I get current config of the web application without using HttpContext?

Tags: c#, configuration, web-config

I need to get the instance of current configuration in my web application. I found that I can get it in the following way:

```
Configuration configuration = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration( HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath);
```

But in some parts of my project I have no **HttpContext** so I need to get the instance of the config without using the **HttpContext**.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.NET OpenWebConfiguration failing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13936432/asp-net-openwebconfiguration-failing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to get the `web.config` like this too:

```
Configuration config = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("/");
```

Comment: This doesn't work, this code opens config in %systemdisk%/inetpub/wwwroot/web.config, and it is not the config that I need. When I do it with parameter `HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath` it returns another web.config.

Comment: I replace "/" with "~" and it works!  
`Configuration config = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~");`

Comment: Yes "/" gets the root web.config, not the current application's web.config, whereas "~" seems to work.

Answer (score 15):

you right Lubochkn ~ does the trick...

```
_webConfigurationManager = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~");
```