# ASP.NET OpenWebConfiguration failing

Tags: asp.net, web-config

I'm trying to open the web configuration so I can encrypt/decrypt it but it's failing. I'm doing this on Web Developer 2010 Express on my desktop where I setup a website as a filesystem. Here are the ways I've tried.

```
Configuration config = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration(HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath);

Configuration config = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~");

Configuration config = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("/");

Configuration config = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("/web.config");

Configuration config = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration(/AppNameHere);
```

Every time I get error: An error occurred loading a configuration file: Failed to map the path '/'.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you trying to access an element in `<appSettings>` or `<applicationSettings>`?

Comment: Actually I'm trying to access connectionStrings section and encrypt it. Maybe I can't do that in the same program that's using the config file.

Comment: Have you tried [`WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.webconfigurationmanager.connectionstrings.aspx)?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you are trying to open the web.config from within the application, you don't need to open it, just use:

```
var section = WebConfigurationManager.GetSection("mySection");
```

Just for you to know, the right parameter is:

```
Configuration config = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~/");
```

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.web.configuration.webconfigurationmanager(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 9):

Run your Visual Studio as Administrator. Cheers! :D

Comment: Have the same problem but when I tried to run my visual studio as administrator, it works like a miracle. :)

Comment: "An error occurred loading a configuration file: Failed to map the path '/'." its mean there is a permission error. and visual studio can not access the "web.config" file. its cause of well done running code sometimes...